# How to create a checkbox column, that if selected will create a strike-through across the entire row in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, formatting

I have a Google Sheets.  I want to set it up so that the first column is checkboxes, and if the checkbox is selected, the entire row gets a strike-through.

How can I accomplish this?

I followed [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18341/is-it-possible-to-add-a-checkbox-button-equivalent-to-a-google-docs-spreadsheet) to add checkboxes, but now I need the row to strike-through if the check box is checked. For example:

**Check box     Phone number             Name**

`no check`         `xxxxxxxxxx`       `John Doe`

`Check`           <strike>`xxxxxxxxxx`</strike>  <strike>`Jane Doe`</strike>

In other words, if a1 = ☑, then strike-through all of Row A.

How do I apply this to the entire sheet?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Conditional formatting: If checkbox ticked in cell A1, change color/strikethrough of cells from B1-F1.**

1. Insert a checkbox from "Insert" tab to A1.
2. Select the cells (B1-F1) that needs to be of different color/strikethrough when a checkbox in A1 is ticked/ selected.
3. From tab above, "Format" > "Conditional formatting".
4. In 'Single color' tab, "Apply to range" = 'B1:F1'
5. "Format cells if" = 'Custom formula is' =  '=$A1=TRUE'
6. "Formatting style" = Select whatever change you want to see in the cells if checkbox ticked.

DONE !!!

Comment: since they implemented "Insert Checkbox" feature, this is now the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming (1) your checkbox is character `☑` (Code 9745) and your entire row runs to ColumnZ, then please select ColumnsB:Z and apply a **Custom formula is** of:

```
=$A1="☑"
```

with formatting of Strike-through and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Comment: I just realized what I was doing wrong, I was using A1 when it was A2... haha

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answer from Rubén, I stumbled into a way to do it across the whole spreadsheet. It worked for me as follow:

[image: screen shot]

1. Insert a checkbox from "Insert" tab to **H1** (in my case)
2. From tab above, "Format" > "Conditional formatting".
3. In 'Single color' tab, "Apply to range" = '**A1:H1032**'
4. "Format cells if" = 'Custom formula is' = '**=$H1=TRUE**'
5. "Formatting style" = Select whatever change you want to see in the cells if checkbox ticked.

For any checkbox that I tick, it will now apply the formatting style to that given row only.

Comment: Should be correct answer.

Comment: To then apply this single row's formatting to a range of rows with their own checkboxes select the newly formatted row and use the format painter to box-select the range you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do a: "Text Contains: TRUE" or "Text Contains: FALSE" check here.

Answer (score -1):

It's also interesting to note that you must include the $ symbol in order to get multi-column coverage. To me, it seems a slightly counterintuitive.

[image: Difference]

Answer (score -1):

That is a great question

If you wish to make a entire row a certain color

1. Insert `Checkbox`
2. Go to `Conditional Formatting`
3. Add a Rule
4. Make the drop down `Custom Formula`
5. For `Value or Formula` Type `=$A1=TRUE` this will cause whatever range you set to turn to that color. If you want the default color to be Red when not selected.
6. Add a New rule
7. Repeat steps 4-5, But this time type `=$A1=FALSE`
8. On Formatting options with color, Press where it says `Default` And Click the `S` with a Dash on it!