# Add a CheckBox with a script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

How can I use a script to add a `CheckBox` to a `Sheet`?

This is probaly trivial but I could not find a single example online and the `CheckBox` class isn't even mentioned in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/).

From the GUI, I would go Insert -> `CheckBox`.

Setting the value of the cell to either TRUE or FALSE doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Short answer

Add the checkbox from the Google Sheets UI, then use one of the copyTo
methods of [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).

## Explanation

NOTE: On [April 19, 209](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#april_19_2019) Google included on the Google Apps Script release notes the `requireCheckbox` method. See more details on [my other answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/122344/88163).

The Google Apps Script Spreadsheet service doesn't include a methods for everything that could be done through the Google Sheets user interface. This is the case of the Insert > Checkbox which is a pretty new feature.

Even the Record macro feature can't do this. The following was recorded one momento ago

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function InsertCheckbox() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  /*
   * Added to show the missing Insert > Checkbox step
   */
  spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

NOTE: If you don't want to pass all the cell properties (borders, formulas, background, etc. instead of `SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL` use `SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION`.

Related Q on Stack Overflow

- [Placing checkboxes in Google Sheets using Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50466080/1595451)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed and it works without issues. I figured it might be something realted to copying it, I hope there's gonna be a better way in the future as they improve the docs and the script service

Comment: @Andrew : I think that you should post your edit suggestion as a new answer rather than a edit to this one.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

Use the <s>undocumented</s> method `requireCheckbox`

NOTE: On [April 19, 209](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#april_19_2019) Google included on the Google Apps Script release notes the `requireCheckbox` method.

## Example

```
function addCheckboxToA1() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1');
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX;
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
    .requireCheckbox()
    .build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

## Explanation

The Apps Script IDE autocomplete feature shows several methods that aren't documented on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/. One of this methods <s>is</s> was `requireCheckbox()` which is shown as a `newDataValidation()` method.

## References

- [Class DataValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder)
- [Placing checkboxes in Google Sheets using Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50466080/1595451)