# How can I convert existing boolean cells into checkboxes in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I am using Google Sheets and I would like to convert some boolean columns (already filled with True/False values) into the "new" (launched April 2018) Tick box format.
This would be handy to update the values with a simple click/keypress.

[image: From booleans to checkboxes]

However, I don't understand how to convert TRUE/FALSE cells into the Tick box format in bulk. I tried using copy/paste special of formats (from the tick boxes to the boolean cells), but to no avail.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

right-click on the cell and select **Data validation** where:

[image]

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Sure! Have a look: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BJxecEuJSReruPz_77jRVjb943aHpN0BD83Ipm_NKfc/

Answer (score 5):

I just found out that one way is the following:

1. Create a bunch of Tick boxes of the right size (desired rows x columns) using Insert > Tick Box after selecting the desired range
2. Copy the existing boolean values
3. "Paste special" them *as values* into the empty Tick boxes created at 1.

Not very elegant but seems to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

...you can try something like this if you need the checkbox to be the return/result of formula evaluation:

```
=IF(A1=1;   
    IMAGE("https://i.imgur.com/DgTwvYi.png");
    IMAGE("https://i.imgur.com/8AxCgKZ.png"))
```